Ethernet Disabled after software update reboot 5/4/2024 22.04.4 LTS -solved but WHY?
Symptoms: No Internet, Networking Icon at the top is gone, the settings gui shows no interfaces. ifconfig by itself shows the loopback interface and nothing else, but an ifconfig -a shows any and all interfaces including 2 usb to ethernet interfaces that were added on the fly when plugged in. Reboot did not help and the added interfaces though visible with an ifconfig -a, had no link light or connectivity.  Incidentally, ip at the command line had the same results as infconfig and ifconfig -a. I found a doc that said use lshw -C network which gave the first clue as to how I could resolve this as the command showed that the ethernet connections were Disabled. Further Googling had me stumble across a simalar solution but I had to create a file /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/allow-unmanaged-devices.com with the contents unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma,except:type:ethernet
and restart networking but that didn't work. I started looking for other solutions and came across the one I listed here. I posted in hopes of helping someone else that may have had this issue. Clearly it has been going on for a while. My question is why must we override the network-manager thingy that was working fine for 6 months and through tons of updates and reboots? Do I/we just leave this like this forever? Is this the correct solution for this issue? If indeed this is the case, then why does Ubuntu 22.xx still ship with this? I am trying make the jump from windows. I have advised friends to try Ubuntu and I am the guy who they are going to call when this happens. Furthermore, as a fan of Open Source and Ubuntu I would like to see it succeed in gaining a significant foothold in the marketplace. However, issues like these are going to be big stumbling blocks for Ubuntu. Failure of all networking on a machine that a user depends on is going to leave a bad taste in that users mouth. No one that I have advised to consider running Ubuntu would be comfortable with a fix where they are editing files through a terminal session to get networking restarted.
So, to summarize, I had pending software updates and did a reboot, upon reboot, my networking interfaces disappeared. The solution that worked is to Edit 10-globally-managed-devices.conf with the values listed below. And my post here is a request and a comment:

The request is if anyone knows why this happens if they would kindly point me to a whitepaper so I can understand what happened.
The comment is that I am a fan of Ubuntu and would like to see it more prevalent in the marketplace. But without a more reliable solution that won't leave users high and dry, and no networking on a primary computer is indeed high and dry, Ubuntu will continue to be a fringe OS that doesn't enjoy wide spread adaptation by the masses due to its high maintenance. my .02

SOLUTION THAT WORKED WAS-
Edit file /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf and change its content from :
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

To:
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:ethernet,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

And then run :
sudo service network-manager restart


But why do I have to do this? This was listed as an answer for v.17.04 but there doesn't seem to be an answer why this is happening.
This cost me 2 hours while I was working on something and man is that frustrating. I just don't get the why it keeps happening and the fix is to unmanage devices whatever that means?

Please [edit] your question and tell us what problem these changes fix. What are the original symptoms? Your title says ethernet was disabled after a software update but that a reboot fixed it? So what do these commands fix? Please clarify your question so we can understand what you need.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you for this. I understand your frustration, and your effort here really saved me. That said, you should really adjust the question so you can also post the solution as an answer. I'll give it an updoot.
